# How to restore the Windows 10 Explorer Ribbon?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, restore

I once fiddled a bit with theming in Windows 10, using software like Windows Classic Shell, because the themes used did not support the default windows 10 explorer.

Now that I've uninstalled those tools again (using Revo Uninstaller which aims to remove all leftover files and registry entries) I seem to be stuck with an explorer without a ribbon bar. Excuse the German in the Screenshot:

[image: Windows Explorer without Ribbon]

As you can see, the ribbon functionality has been moved to this little menu bar.
Also the preview menu seems to be enabled, which, to my knowledge, requires a registry tweak.

I know I can easily undo the preview pane, but how do I restore the rest? (Besides reinstalling Windows)

Comment: Yes, I restarted both Windows Explorer and the computer itself.

Comment: Check if it changed the **ExplorerFrame.dll** in system32 folder or in syswow64 folder.

Comment: Pretty sure it did. But how can I restore it?

Comment: @Biswa yes my OS is 64 bit and there are multiple ExplorerFrame.dll files, non of them having a fitting timestamp.

Comment: I'm trying each of those files now, I think the originial one was lost... can't I obtain it somewhere else?

Comment: @Biswa help me out here: I replaced the ExplorerFrame.dll and now I can't start an Explorer instance... and I can't replace the file from within cmd (elevated prompt)! (`del /F C:\Windows\System32\ExplorerFrame.dll`)

Comment: @Biswa and it doesn't help to take ownership `takeown /f ExplorerFrame.dll` and edit the permissions `cacls ExplorerFrame.dll /G MyUsernameHere:F` (still returns `ACCESS DENIED`!)

Comment: Fixed it using PowerShell, no luck with those files.